# How to return same number of row from both queries with UNION?

Tags: sql, group-by, union, sybase, sap-ase

I have two queries that use `SUM()` with `GROUP BY`. Each query should return same number or rows. In this case my SQL in Sybase returns the rows separate instead on the same line. Here is my query:

```
SELECT type_id, category_id, category_name, type_code, amount, awarded
    FROM (
        SELECT
            type_id, 
            category_id,
            category_name, 
            type_code,
            CASE 
                WHEN category_id = 1 THEN SUM(amount)
                WHEN category_id = 2 THEN SUM(amount)
                WHEN category_id = 3 THEN SUM(amount)
                WHEN category_id = 4 THEN SUM(amount)
            END AS amount,
            0 AS awarded
        FROM Table 1
        GROUP BY category_id, type_id, category_id, type_code
        UNION
        SELECT
            null AS type_id, 
            ga.grant_category_id,
            '' AS category_name, 
            null AS type_code,
            0 AS amount,
            CASE 
                WHEN t2.category_id = 1 THEN SUM(t2.awarded)
                WHEN t2.category_id = 2 THEN SUM(t2.awarded)
                WHEN t2.category_id = 3 THEN SUM(t2.awarded)
                WHEN t2.category_id = 4 THEN SUM(t2.awarded)
            END AS awarded
        FROM Table2 t2
            INNER JOIN Table3 t3
                ON t2.rec_id = t3.rec_id
        GROUP BY t2.category_id
    ) x
    GROUP BY x.category_id
```

Query result looks like this:

```
type_id  category_id  category_name  type_code   amount   awarded
   1         2             TEST 2      REST     51804.00    0.00
   1         4             TEST 4      REST     39398.00    0.00
   1         3             TEST 3      REST     79922.00    0.00
   1         1             TEST 1      REST     70927.00    0.00
  null       1             null        null       0.00     96013.00
  null       2             null        null       0.00     78759.00
  null       3             null        null       0.00     21436.00
  null       4             null        null       0.00     74602.00
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
 type_id  category_id  category_name  type_code   amount   awarded
   1         2             TEST 2      REST     51804.00    96013.00
   1         4             TEST 4      REST     39398.00    78759.00
   1         3             TEST 3      REST     79922.00    21436.00
   1         1             TEST 1      REST     70927.00    74602.00
```

How to achieve this output? Thank you.

Comment: I think you want a `JOIN`, not a `UNION`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Join doesn't work for this case. There is more complex data manipulation behind the screen.

Comment: How do you tell which lines from either side of the UNION are to be combined into one line?

Comment: @PhilipKelley All of them should be combined. The category_id is the column that should be joined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When @Gordon talked about JOINs, he meant make them subqueries and join them. The following presumse that categories may or may not be returned by either query:

```
SELECT
   Set1.type_id  --  Where this is not found in Set1, you specified null in Set2
  ,ISNULL(Set1.category_id, Set2.grant_category_id)  AS  category_id
  ,ISNULL(Set1.category_name, '')  --  Where this is not found in Set1, you specified <emptyString> in Set2
  ,Set1.type_code  --  Where this is not found in Set1, you specified null in Set2
  ,ISNULL(Set1.amount, 0)  --  Where this is not found in Set1, you specified 0 in Set2
  ,ISNULL(Set2.awarded, 0)  --  Where this is not found in Set2, you specified 0 in Set1
 FROM (
        SELECT
            type_id, 
            category_id,
            category_name, 
            type_code,
            SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN category_id between 1 and 4 THEN amount
                    ELSE 0
                END) AS amount
        FROM Table1
        GROUP BY
            type_id, 
            category_id,
            category_name, 
            type_code,
      ) Set1
 FULL OUTER JOIN (   
        SELECT
            t2.grant_category_id,
            SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN t2.category_id between 1 and 4 THEN t2.awarded
                END) AS awarded
        FROM Table2 t2
            INNER JOIN Table3 t3
                ON t2.rec_id = t3.rec_id
        GROUP BY
            t2.grant_category_id,
    ) Set2
  ON Set2.grant_category_Id = Set1.category_id
```

Disclaimer: I could not check the syntax on this, so some minor debugging may be required.

Comment: I had to tweak few things because Sybase is "great". Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is that what You want?

```
SELECT type_id, category_id, category_name, type_code, amount, awarded
    FROM (
        SELECT
            t1.type_id, 
            t1.category_id,
            t1.category_name, 
            t1.type_code,
            SUM(t1.amount) amount,
            SUM(t2.awarded) awarded
        FROM Table1 t1
            INNER JOIN Table2 t2
                ON t1.category_id = t2.category_id
            INNER JOIN Table3 t3
                ON t2.rec_id = t3.rec_id
        GROUP BY 
            t1.type_id, 
            t1.category_id,
            t1.category_name, 
            t1.type_code
        )    x
```

Moreover, in your example, it seems to me that there is an error. 
Shouldn't it will be like that? Where key for *Table1* and *Table2* is *category_id*

type_id  category_id  category_name  type_code   amount   awarded
   1         2             TEST 2      REST     51804.00    78759.00
   1         4             TEST 4      REST     39398.00    74602.00
   1         3             TEST 3      REST     79922.00    21436.00
   1         1             TEST 1      REST     70927.00    96013.00